# Не переведены сообщения для анонимного участника, публикующего ответ

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Извините, я плохо говорю по-русски, но мне довелось увидеть раздел этого сайта, что до сих пор английские, а именно экран анонимный участник получает, когда он хочет, чтобы внести свой вклад в ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Thank you for this report. I've clarified the title. This is probably caused by the recent SE data center migration. Lots of strings were broken in the process, looks like they didn't handle them in a proper way. )

Answer (score 2):

Перевод уже есть. Но сделан он не средствами transifex:

> [image: ответ без регистрации]

И, кстати, не хватает `ё` и запятых кое-где.

Comment: Значит это в базе справки, Николас больше об этом знает.